# Pandas dataframe: Getting row indices from criteria 1, sorted by criteria 2

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have data frames with the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Col1' : [4,5,6,7], 'Col2' : [10,20,30,40], 'Col3' : [100,50,-30,-50], 'Col4' : ['AAA', 'BBB', 'AAA', 'CCC']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index = ['R1','R2','R3','R4'])

    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R1     4    10   100  AAA
R2     5    20    50  BBB
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R4     7    40   -50  CCC
```

I know how to get the row indices from the rows in which `Col2` lies between 10 and 40:

```
indeces = (df.Col2 > 10) & (df.Col2 < 40)
```

However, how could I, for example, get those indices sorted by the  values in `Col4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df[indeces].sort_values(['Col4'])

    Col1  Col2  Col3 Col4
R3     6    30   -30  AAA
R2     5    20    50  BBB
```